# Sort array of objects with Lodash sortBy instead of custom sort function

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have the following data:

```
phones: {
  'home': {
    number: '1234567890',
    primary: false,
    preferred: false
  },
  'mobile': {
    number: '2134567890',
    primary: true,
    preferred: true
  },
  'work': {
    number: '1234567809',
    primary: false,
    preferred: true
  }
}
```

I'm passing this to a React component:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <MyComponent data={
      Object.keys(phones)
        .reduce((prev, key) => [...prev, phones[key]], []) // omitting keys
        .sort(this.sortPhoneNumbers)
      } 
    />
  )
}
```

And this is my custom sort function:

```
sortPhoneNumbers: function (a, b) {
  if (a.preferred === b.preferred) {
    return (b.primary - a.primary)
  } else if (a.preferred < b.preferred) {
    return 1
  } else if (a.preferred > b.preferred) {
    return -1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
```

I want to use [Lodash sortBy function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) instead though.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it on the result obtained from `Object.keys().reduce` like

```
<MyComponent data={
      _.sortBy(Object.keys(phones)
        .reduce((prev, key) => [...prev, phones[key]], []), 'preferred')
      } 
    />
```

Comment: The output of this will not be quite correct. I need the `preferred` phones to show first in the list. If it's a `primary` as well phone it should always be first. The way this is right now is the phones that are neither of the above show first and after them come the preferred phones.